# How to return failure with an event subscriber?

Tags: event-subscribers

I have an event subscriber that deducts a credit when someone makes a booking. If there are no credits left, how do I return a failure and stop the booking  being made?

The subscriber is acting on ENTITY_INSERT.

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
  return [
    EntityHookEvents::ENTITY_INSERT => [
      'redeemTicket',
      -20,
    ],
  ];
}
```

I've tried

```
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('This booking needs a valid ticket!');
```

Although this results in a 'white screen'

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: This booking needs a valid ticket! in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (
```

Following the drupal event [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/creating-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events).

Comment: What is the FQCN of EntityHookEvents?

Comment: Drupal\core_event_dispatcher\EntityHookEvents;

Comment: What is the Drupal version and what is the origin of the core_event_dispatcher module?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when throwing `AccessDeniedHttpException` in the middle of an SQL operation?

Comment: Probably worth noting that hook_entity_insert() _runs once the entity has been stored_. So there’s nothing to stop at that point. You probably want to listen for a presave event or hook_entity_create instead

Comment: `git log -S EntityHookEvents`: no results in Drupal Core. What is `core_event_dispatcher`?

Comment: @cilefen It is one of the modules in the [Hook Event Dispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher) project.

Comment: I agree, you want to use presave or something else.

Comment: Yes, I tried presave. It is a more logical point. Same white screen of death, but I think that is a weakness in the bookable-calendar module which doesn't try to catch exceptions in save. I started adapting that module to try/catch, but think that it might be better although less general to create its own PREBOOKING event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's better to stop the save operation as soon as possible, but in this case, storing a content entity via SQL, the result is the same. Both hooks are in one SQL transaction, only that in the original code the SQL database has more to rollback. It might be a better idea to check the condition when validating the input data and only throw exceptions in database operations if anything unexpected happens.

BTW this is not a Symfony topic because you are using events dispatched from Drupal hooks. So it's the same as if you would put the code directly in these hooks. The referenced documentation is about events dispatched by the Symfony kernel.